# Instantiating and closing Realm instances

Tags: android, persistence, realm

I'm a bit confused about how/when/why to close the realm instances. In the whole course of my application I've never invoked `.close()` on my realm instance, because if I close it I am no longer able to use the realm objects I deal with. Maybe the point to close the realm instance would be in my Application `onDestroy()` in the same way I create my instance in my Application `onCreate()`. Actually I play with a singleton instance of Realm [*] created in my Application.

Is this (a Realm singleton) a good approach? and What can happen if I never close my Realm?

[*] In fact now I'm thinking in a Flywheight collection of Realm instances, storing an instance per thread instead, as now Service Intent came to play in my app and need access Realm from its thread. I think here (in Service Intent), I can close realm in `onDestroy()` as thread will be finished doing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm handles caching internally and will make it as performant as possible. So you should not be afraid of calling `Realm.getInstance()`. The reason is that `close()` is required is that you might risk leaking memory which eventually will kill your app.

In short, you should not make a Realm singleton or other caching pattern yourself.
You can read more about best practices for controlling the Realm lifecycle here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Note that `Application.onDestroy()` does not exists and `Application.onTerminate()` is not called for normal apps.

Comment: first thanks for your time. Could you please explain a little bit more the point of risk leaking memory if not closing Realm? I've started to face problems of type: "IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable" and accessing Realm from wrong thread. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Realm allocates a number of native ressources under the hood. Not closing Realms will keep those around even if they no longer needed. A bigger problem though is that open Realms keep a hold of the version they use, so on background threads that doesn't auto-update the Realm will have to keep track of more changes which translate to your Realm file increasing in size more than it has to.